# SQLAlchemy class __init__() meets takes at least 5 non-keyword arguments error

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, init

I was wrote some code

User class for SQLAlcemy

```
##############models.py
class User(Base,UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, Sequence('seq_user_id'), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50), unique=True, index = True, nullable = False)
    email = Column(String(120), unique=True, index = True, nullable = False)
    password = Column(String(128), nullable = False)
    registerdate = Column(Date, nullable = False)

    def __init__(self, name, email, password, registerdate):
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
        self.password = password
        self.registerdate = datetime.datetime.now()

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % (self.name)

    def is_authenticated(self):
        return True

    def is_active(self):
        return True

    def is_anonymous(self):
        return False

    def get_id(self):
        return unicode(self.id)
```

then I wrote some code for create test user

```
############## frontend.py
@app.route('/createuser')
def createuser():
    user_jacky = User(name='jacky',email='jacky@test.com',password=md5.new('123').hexdigest())
    db_session.add(user_jacky)
    db_session.commit()
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

When I access http://test.com/createuser, system told me that "TypeError: **init**() takes at least 5 non-keyword arguments (4 given)". I read the document of SQLALchemy again, that's same as my code, does not need to pass value to the self. What happend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `__init__` expects you to pass in a `registerdate`, but you aren't providing one when `__init__` is called through this line:

```
User(name='jacky',email='jacky@test.com',password=md5.new('123').hexdigest())
```

If the `registerdate` should always be `now()`, you can leave out the parameter:

```
def __init__(self, name, email, password):
    self.name = name
    self.email = email
    self.password = password
    self.registerdate = datetime.datetime.now()
```

If you want to be able to provide a `registerdate`, but it should default to `now()`, you can do this:

```
def __init__(self, name, email, password, registerdate=None):
    self.name = name
    self.email = email
    self.password = password
    self.registerdate = registerdate or datetime.datetime.now()
```

Comment: Oh, yes. I miss the last parameter. I was so careless. Thank you!